# How to lint Namespace based on folder's name?

Tags: php, phpcs, php-cs-fixer, psalm-php

I know PHP CS Fixer and Psalm to lint PHP. I've been using both of them. But I can't find a way to lint  / validate my namespace name based on the folder.

For example, in folder `Tests/Controllers/V1`, I have `MyControllerTest.php`, and it has the following codes:

```
<?php

// I should have correct namespace based on folder name not V2 but V1
namespace Tests\Controllers\V2;


.. ... my code
```

How can I lint the above code with correct namespace?

*NOTE: I am using PHP 7.3.*

Comment: using backlash Tests\Controllers\V2

Comment: @Jerson yap updated, any idea how to lint the namespace?

Comment: As far as I am aware it's not a PHP coding violation to have namespace mismatching folder names, and it's not the job of a linter to find those mistakes either. Sorry but I don't think anyone is going to be able to give you an answer that satisfies your criteria. If it was me, and I had to catch these mistakes, I'd probably write a python or bash script to do such checks.

Comment: @Kodaloid, all rules in PHP CS Fixer / Psalm are not PHP coding violation neither. It's just rules for better code and spot common mistakes. And I need Namespace check rule.